# can I export VPN certificate from OSX to Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, certificates

I have configuration file for VPN that works on OSX with Tunnelblick.

As far as I understand, the same VPN certificate can be used from different machines.

So I copied the configuration file the `*.key` file and the`*.cert` files from the OSX machine to an Ubuntu machine.

I tried to open the VPN connection with the command:

```
sudo openvpn --config file.ovpn
```

and also with

```
sudo openvpn file.ovpn
```

However I am not able to connect.

I am getting some warnings:

```
WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:5: block-outside-dns (2.4.4)
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:6: register-dns (2.4.4)
WARNING: INSECURE cipher with block size less than 128 bit (64 bit).
```

How to use the same certificate I have been using on OSX with Tunnelblick on Ubuntu?

**NOTE**

Actually I am getting not only warnings but errors too:

```
Wed Oct 10 10:10:37 2018 Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:5: block-outside-dns (2.4.4)
Wed Oct 10 10:10:37 2018 Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:6: register-dns (2.4.4)
```

**NOTE 2**

Importing the `*.ovpn` file from the interface works, so the file is correct.

Comment: Why not try re-downloading the config file and certificates from your service provider (and choosing Linux as your OS if it's offered as an option), instead of trying to convert from macOS?

Comment: It was sent to me and it should not be dependent on any platform, so there is no such an option. The only doubt I have is if I can use from different machines. I did not do any conversion, I just copied it and used it as it was.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi - did you ever solve this?

Comment: Partially: I cannot make it work from the Terminal but I did make it work setting the VPN from the WiFi options of the user interface